# How do I properly implement MongoDB error handling in Express?

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, express, mongoose

Here I have a simple user repository. For creating the user I used a `try-catch` block to catch the unique constraint errors and throw a BadRequestError which I later catch in the global handler and send an appropriate response. For errors that are not known to me, I crash the app with `process.exit(1);`.

But, having a `try-catch` for every db query, and then trying to detect the exact reason by checking the error codes feels repetitive (and there is a high chance I will forget checking some known errors).

I can choose omit the `try-catch` blocks and handle them in my middleware but then I'd be exposing the low level MongoDb errors in a higher level module (middleware).

So,

1. Should I be using try-catch everytime I make a db query?
2. Should I try to detect the exact error type here as I'm doing with the duplicate field error? And how should I be react to both kind of errors (known-unknown) in the repository?
3. Should I crash the app on unknown errors? Like if I set the `ascending` to `2`, it would throw an error. If I don't catch it and throw a known error like I'm doing with unique constraint here, it would crash the app but that doesn't feel great. Should I just reply with 500 and keep the app running?

```
@Service()
export class UserRepository {

  async getAllSorted(ascending: boolean): Promise<UserDto[]> {
    let sort = {};
    sort = { createdAt: ascending ? 1 : -1 };
    const users = await User.find({}).sort(sort);
    return users.map(toUserDto);
  };

  async create(user: UserCreateDto): Promise<UserDto> {
    const newUser = new User(user);
    try {
      const createdUser = await newUser.save();
      return toUserDto(createdUser);
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.code === 11000) { // duplicate field error
        console.error(error);
        throw new BadRequestError('Unique constraint failed while creating the user.', error.keyValue);
      } else {
        throw error;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I know this is a very simple app for this much complexity but I'm trying to learn the best practices. Thank you.

Comment: Other way is by using promise

Comment: The fact that you are identifying these approaches and weighing them against each other is a very good sign that you are on a good path for learning. I don’t think there is a right or wrong in general here - it depends on the specifics of the app. Maybe you can always “ignore” the 11000 error or maybe there are situations where you do want to crash the app if uniqueness violation is attempted. You might just need to pick an approach and then adjust as you learn and grow. Or maybe someone else has a better answer than me :)